# While and for loop not working

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I have a question and I think there is a really easy solution for, but i'm busy for 12 hours now and I don't know the solution for this problem.

I have a database with several data. The important data is the time that I save in the database. I want to build a module that give the data 08:00 to 17:00. For example:

```
08:00 available
09:00 not available
10:00 available
11:00 available
12:00 available
13:00 available
14:00 available
15:00 available
16:00 available
17:00 not available
```

I'll using the following code

```
$mysql['avail'] = mysql_query("SELECT time FROM `module` WHERE `date` = '" . $dbdate . "' ORDER BY date");
while($avail = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql['avail'])){

  $hour = date('s',$avail['time']);

  for ($i = 8;$i <= 17; $i++) {

    if($hour == $i) {

        echo $i.':00&nbsp;not available<br />';

    } else {


        echo $i.':00&nbsp;available<br />';

    }

  } 

}
```

Now I get the following output:

```
08:00 available
09:00 not available
10:00 available
11:00 available
12:00 available
13:00 available
14:00 available
15:00 available
16:00 available
17:00 available

08:00 available
09:00 available
10:00 available
11:00 available
12:00 available
13:00 available
14:00 available
15:00 available
16:00 available
17:00 not available
```

Whatever I try, I've no solution to get it right. Is there anybody that can help me?

Comment: the problem is no clear

Comment: Your query might be vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: The answer from Vadim is the right solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to fetch all your available hours at first and then make one loop with your timetable and check for each hour if it is in available hours array.

Something like this one

```
$not_available_hours = array();
$mysql['avail'] = mysql_query("SELECT time FROM `module` WHERE `date` = '" . $dbdate . "' ORDER BY date");
while($avail = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql['avail'])){
    $not_available_hours[] = date('s',$avail['time']);
}

for ($i = 8;$i <= 17; $i++) {
    if (in_array($i, $not_available_hours) {
        echo $i.':00&nbsp;not available<br />';
    } else {
        echo $i.':00&nbsp;available<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not enough credits but this was the solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use mysql `HOUR` function to get hour.

```
$mysql['avail'] = mysql_query("SELECT HOUR(time) as `hour` FROM `module` WHERE `date` = '" . $dbdate . "' ORDER BY date");
while($avail = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql['avail'])){

  $hour = $avail['hour'];

  for ($i = 8;$i <= 17; $i++) {

    if($hour == $i) {

        echo $i.':00&nbsp;not available<br />';

    } else {


        echo $i.':00&nbsp;available<br />';

    }

  } 

}
```

and you should not use `mysql` functions but `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will produce desire result :

```
$mysql['avail'] = mysql_query("SELECT time FROM `module` WHERE `date` = '" . $dbdate . "' ORDER BY date");
$notAvailable = array();
while($avail = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql['avail'])){
 $notAvailable[] = date('s',$avail['time'])
}
  for ($i = 8;$i <= 17; $i++) {

    if(in_array($i, $notAvailable) {
        echo $i.':00&nbsp;not available<br />';
    } else {
        echo $i.':00&nbsp;available<br />';
    }

  }
```