# Loop through an array while looping through a query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP/MySQL request returning data (ie: called "my_request").
I fetch through the results, and there comes my trouble...
For each result, I need to check if the value is also in a hard-coded array (ie: called my_array").
I get the expected result, but it's echoed twice.

I should have:
- my_request
- while/loop through the results
- echo 1 if the data is in my_array
- echo 0 if the data is *not* in my_array

so : 00110000

I get : 0010000000010000

After serching here and there, I tried :
- store the result / end the query loop / then loop through the array : no result

Here's a piece of the code :

```
$my_array = array('Monday' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00'), 'Tuesday' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00') /* and so on 'til saturday */ );

$query = " SELECT date, start FROM table WHERE id=2 AND date='2016-12-08' ORDER BY start ";
$resultats = $conn->query($query) or die ("Error :" . mysql_error());

while ($hours = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultats))
{
extract($hours);

echo" ( $date / $start ) "; /* results are ok , let's say I have 2 resultst ie: 9:00 and 10:00 */

foreach ($my_array as $hour) {
    if( $hour == $start ) { echo"done"; } else { "fail"; }
}
}
```

this is where I get the double result! and can't find where I do wrong...
Do I have to go back to store the result of the request, then use it for the array loop ? But how ? Or anything else ?
Any clue ? thanks

Comment: Please notice that `$my_array` is two-dimensional.

Comment: How does that changes the output ? (I mean, I have no problem reading the array nor the data from the request, that's why I can't figure out what I do wrong to get multiple results where I need to get only one...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found this [While and for loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436321/while-and-for-loop-not-working?rq=1)
I managed to work around the answer (by Vadim) to make my own now-working stuff ^^, so if it can be of any help to someone...

```
/* query used below has been prepared at the beginning of the script */
$not_available_hours = array();
$myday = $specialHours[$theday];

$results = $stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->bind_result($date, $start);
$stmt1->store_result();

if ($stmt1->num_rows > 0) {

while($stmt1->fetch()){

$start = strtotime($start);
$debut = date("G:i", $start);

$not_available_hours[] = $debut;
}

foreach ($myday as $hour) {
    if (in_array($hour, $not_available_hours)) {
    $finish = strtotime($hour) + 3600; 
    $fin = date("G:i", $finish);
    echo"already booked !"; /* grey line */
    } else {
$finish = strtotime($hour) + 3600; 
$fin = date("G:i", $finish);
echo"get it !"; /* available -> green line */
}
}
```